# Vertically-align contents of header tag

Tags: css, html

I've been reading alot about vertically aligning text in CSS.  I can't understand why it was so easy in HTML, but it's not in CSS.

Anyway, my question is, I have the following:
In my HTML document:

```
<header>
    <h1> My Website </h1>
</header>
```

In my CSS style sheet:

```
header
{
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: BCCCCC;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I would just like to know the easiest, most simple way to vertically align the text, so that it can be shifted to the middle of the header section, or to the bottom of the header section.

If my question been already been asked, please let me know where.

Thank you.

Comment: It was never easy in HTML, except in table cells. And it still is.

Answer (score 6):

Give `height & line-height` of the `header` same for `vertical align center'. Like this:

```
header
{
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #BCCCCC;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    background:red;
    display:block;

}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/3QGqf/

**UPDATED**
If you want the text at the bottom then you can use `position:absolute` or `display:table` property for this. Here is the example with `display:table` property.

### http://jsfiddle.net/3QGqf/2/

Comment: Thanks, what if i wanted bottom?